# How do I troubleshoot an exception in Startup class in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        throw new Exception("boo");
    }
 }
```

Detailed error logging is enabled.
I don't use Application Insights and I don't want to.

The reply that will be marked as answer to this question will show:

1. The path and file name pattern of a log file that will contain the stack trace and also the text of the exception i.e. "boo".

or

2. A technique for displaying the error message on a page such as `.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` (if you can show how to use `.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` that would be great).  I am in fact aware to not use `.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` in prod.

Comment: Don't. I do not know why people downvoted it but for me the answer is new to me and valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#startup-exception-handling):

> Only the hosting layer can handle exceptions that take place during app startup. Using the Web Host, you can [configure how the host behaves in response to errors during startu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#detailed-errors)p with the [`captureStartupErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host#capture-startup-errors) and [`detailedErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host#detailed-errors) keys.

So you can configure your `WebHost` this way:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
    .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true");
```